# pgfplots won't produce error bars

Tags: pgfplots

The following error is thrown when I try to compile the MWE below:

```
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/error' and I am going to ignore it.
Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

I'm running MacTeX 2012 with a fully up-to-date distro.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xmin = 0,
    xmax = 30,
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = 0.45
  ]
    \addplot[
      color = black,
      only marks,
      error bars/.cd,
        y dir = both,
        y explicit,
    ] table[
      y = set1,
      error = stdev% comment out for MWE
    ] {
      mcg set1   set2   set3   stdev
      0   0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
      5   0.1031 0.0922 0.0819 0.01
      10  0.1935 0.2137 0.2132 0.01
      15  0.2875 0.2926 0.2888 0.003
      20  0.3373 0.3394 0.3462 0.005
      30  0.4396 0.4328 0.4362 0.003
    };

    \addplot[
      color = red,
      domain = 0:30
    ] {-0.0003*x^2 + 0.0224*x - 0.001};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are probably looking for the `y error` instead of the `error` key.

Comment: Oh wow. I'm silly. I completely looked over the "y" before the "error" in the documentation. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for one of the following keys:

- **`y error`** that expects a column name (here: `stdev`),
- `y error index` that expects a column index, or
- `y error expr` that expects an expression.

I also added `mark options={mark size=.75}` to get a better visual output.
The default size looks to big for these errors.

### Code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xmin = 0,
    xmax = 30,
    ymin = 0,
    ymax = 0.45
  ]
    \addplot[
      color = black,
      only marks,
      mark options={mark size=.75},
      error bars/.cd,
        y dir = both,
        y explicit,
    ] table[
      y = set1,
      y error = stdev
    ] {
      mcg set1   set2   set3   stdev
      0   0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
      5   0.1031 0.0922 0.0819 0.01
      10  0.1935 0.2137 0.2132 0.01
      15  0.2875 0.2926 0.2888 0.003
      20  0.3373 0.3394 0.3462 0.005
      30  0.4396 0.4328 0.4362 0.003
    };

    \addplot[
      color = red,
      domain = 0:30
    ] {-0.0003*x^2 + 0.0224*x - 0.001};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]